# When entering a login password, password to be checked doesn't ==

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, md5

I have a PHP login form which uses a MD5 hash for my password security (I know MD5 is bad, I am going to change its later on; it is just for developing purposes right now). When I use `==` on the password comparing it won't log me in.

Does md5ing return a string or something else maybe because in my database I just have the string of the word password as if it were MD5'ed ("5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d83")? This is the beginning stages of my login I will be added prepare statements and all that as well after I better research them and get this working.

Also the domain I was given is running PHP version 5.3.28, so `password_verify()` won't work for this development site.

The index page (login)

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {

        // Include the databas connection script
    include_once("includes/connect.inc.php");

    // Set the posted data from the form into local variables
    $usname = $_POST['username'];
    $paswd  = $_POST['password'];

    $usname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $usname);

    $sql          = "SELECT * FROM dealerEmployees WHERE firstName = '$usname' LIMIT 1";
    $query        = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $row          = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $uid          = $row[0];
    $dbUsname     = $row[1];
    $firstName    = $row[1];
    $lastName     = $row[2];
    $dbPassword   = $row[3];
    $permission   = $row[4];
    $address      = $row[5];
    $email        = $row[6];
    $phone        = $row[7];
    $profilePhoto = $row[8];
    $bannerPhoto  = $row[9];

    // Check if the username and the password they entered was correct
    if ($usname == $dbUsname) {

            if($paswd == $dbPassword){
            // Set session 
            $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
            $_SESSION['userId'] = $uid;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
            $_SESSION['firstName'] = $firstName;
            $_SESSION['lastName'] = $lastName;
            //$_SESSION['password'] = $dbPassword;
            $_SESSION['permission'] = $permission;
            $_SESSION['address'] = $address;
            $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['profilePhoto'] = $profilePhoto;
            $_SESSION['bannerPhoto'] = $bannerPhoto;
            // Now direct to users feed
            header("Location: hub.php");
        }
    } else {
        echo "<h2>Oops that username or password combination was incorrect.
        <br /> Please try again.</h2>";
    }

}
?>

<form id="form" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Please Enter Your First Name"/> <br />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Please Enter Your Password"/> <br />
 <button class="button" type="submit">Log In</button>

</form>
```

Comment: "I know MD5 is bad, I am going to change its later on" Why? `password_hash` and `password_verify` are build into PHP and easy to use. Practicing writing bad code is a good way to get used to writing bad code.

Comment: just because the tutorial i watched had md5 in it so when i wrote it I put md5 in it as well. Password_hash is great tho

Comment: Get a better tutorial then. :-)

Comment: Depending on how you inserted it, you should probably not be calling `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on `$paswd` _before_ you call `md5()` on the input. You are hashing the _escaped_ password and therefore storing the hash  for a different password than submitted. Hash first, then escape, but actually as already informed, use `password_hash()`.

Comment: Also, do not `strip_tags()` on the input password. If a user creates a password that has something like `<stuff>a1089f`, you will convert it to the _weaker_ password `a1089f` without the user's knowledge.

Comment: `SELECT *` followed by `mysqli_fetch_row` will be *tremendously* fragile, by the way. If you ever add a column it's going to change the array indexes and break everything.

Comment: See my profile page if you want a better tutorial - it uses the function recommended by @ceejayoz, and does a bunch of security things the correct way.

Comment: `=` and `==` are two completely different things. `=` is not a comparison operator.

Comment: Is there any value in storing the user's password in the session? You want to handle this at little as possible, IMO, especially on shared hosting, where sessions have sometimes risked being readable by other customers.

Comment: Ok so i have updated all the code  and description a little bit, still have the issue. As for pass_hash()  i didnt change it yet because the domain im on  only runs PHP version 5.3.28

Comment: There is a [PHP implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) of the password library for PHP 5.3.7+. You can add that to your project, and it will work fine even if the deployment version of PHP is much later.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this is a very bad idea:

```
$paswd  = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
```

If I'm being careful to generate strong passwords, there's a good chance my password may be something like `c5<dZIuJYWUP3>y`. You just turned my password into the very crackable `c5y`.

Using MD5 is also a very bad idea. Use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/password_hash) to take advantage of PHP's built-in handling for the industry-standard bcrypt algorithm. **There's no reason to practice writing bad code.**

> Does md5ing return a string or something else maybe?

Yes, it'll return a 32 character string made up of the 0-9 and a-f characters. The MD5 hash of `password`, for example, is `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`.

> But when I use == on the password comparing it wont log me in.

Then the MD5 hash of the password the user entered doesn't match the MD5 hash you have stored in the database.

For ease of debugging, consider manually editing your database row to use the hash `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`, and try logging in with the password `password`. If this works, you either weren't storing a MD5 hash in the database or you were storing the *wrong* MD5 hash in the database - possibly because of your `strip_tags` stuff.

If it doesn't, you have something more fundamental going on - possibly made easier to debug by using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_row` on your `SELECT *` query.

Comment: FOr the same reason you shouldn't escape the password either. Among other things now the user comes back and tries the password and it fails.

Comment: Ok so i have updated all the code  and description a little bit, still have the issue. As for pass_hash()  i didnt change it yet because the domain im on  only runs PHP version 5.3.28

Comment: @Brady https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat is the backport of those functions for PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.4. Do note that PHP 5.3 was end-of-lifed nearly a year ago and likely contains **major** security issues as a result. It is dangerous to run 5.3. http://php.net/eol.php

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of insecurity in your login script. You need to use prepared statements. Or anyone with a clue could inject you and delete your database or login as admin. You should also use sha512 to hash, it is almost impossible to decrypt.

But to your question:

= is to assign something.

== is to check if they are the same basic value.

=== is to check if they are the same value and same type.

You were assigning $paswd to $dbPassword in your if statement instead of checking if they match.
Corrected the if:

```
// Check if the username and the password they entered was correct
    if ($usname === $dbUsname && $paswd === $dbPassword) {
        // Set session 
        $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
        $_SESSION['userId'] = $uid;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
        $_SESSION['firstName'] = $firstName;
        $_SESSION['lastName'] = $lastName;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $dbPassword;
        $_SESSION['permission'] = $permission;
        $_SESSION['address'] = $address;
        $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['profilePhoto'] = $profilePhoto;
        $_SESSION['bannerPhoto'] = $bannerPhoto;
        // Now direct to users feed
        header("Location: hub.php");
    } else {
        echo "<h2>Oops that username or password combination was incorrect.
        <br /> Please try again.</h2>";
    }
```

Here is a pretty secure login script. Its just part of it, but if you read it it should really shed some ligh on what you need to do. No offence, but your script is not good.

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
        FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your right, thanks. The issue is that when i do compare them with == it says the information entered isnt correct.

Comment: Remove the escape and striping from the password they enter

Comment: @Brady Then the information isn't correct, for some reason. Time to figure out what it is. Print out `$paswd` and `$dbPassword` for starters and see what their values are. Make sure there's no extra space hiding in one of them - ` test` is not the same as `test`.

Comment: @Brady what IDE are uyou using? You need to debug and check the dbpassword and password when the arrive at the if statement. Also you need to remove checking is the username is same as db username, you are using it in your query it wouldn't return the password if the username was not already matching. Also before you get to the dbpwd=pwd you need to check if your query even returned any rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($usname == $dbUsname && $paswd = $dbPassword) {
```

To execute this sentence also, what you're doing is to set the variable `$paswd` value `$dbPassword`.

The comparison should be more or less like this:

```
if (($usname == $dbUsname) && ($paswd == $dbPassword)) {
```

Comment: OP knows this. "Right now it doesnt matter what the password is as long as the username is right it will log you in. The is because in the if statement that checks if the enter data is the same as the users data in the DB, the username compares with == and the password compares with just = . But when I use == on the password comparing it wont log me in."